# How to force anchor to middle of (external) page instead of top?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page we'll call "Pricing". On that page I have a few links that, when clicked, take the user to an **external** page we'll call "Info" with extended information.

Depending on the link clicked from the "Pricing" page (i.e. `info.html#ref1`, `info.html#ref2`, etc.,) that particular element will be highlighted on the "Info" page.

I've already got the highlighting to work, however I'd like to have that highlighted element centered in the MIDDLE of the page instead of at the top. That is, if the elements to be highlighted are < 50% of the page, then no scrolling required, but if it's > 50%, then that's when scrolling should occur.

I've almost got it working using the following CSS:

```
div.refs p:target {
    background-color: #FFDDDD;
    padding-top; 50%;
}
```

But as you probably already know, that makes the entire top-half of the page that color.

Javascript is welcome.

Comment: Please post the relevant code you have tried so far. Also consider providing an online example on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) or any other online editor to demonstrate the issue in action.

Comment: Exact requirement is not clear from the question. But seems like what you want is "margin-top: 50%;" instead of "padding-top: 50%;". Also, if you want it always visible in same place, use "position: fixed;"

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. It is:

```
padding-top: 50%
```

With a colon and not a semi-colon. It's hard to figure out your idea and problem, without seeing your code, but I think you could do it by changing the `padding-top` to `margin-top`.